# how to use explode in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I wanna do the following task in `pyspark`. Let I have the following dataframe:

df:

```
all_skills           dates  
['A','B']           2020-11-01
['B','I','R']       2020-11-01
['S','H']           2020-11-02
['A','H','S']       2020-11-02
```

In pandas the following code gives me the desired output:

```
`data_ready=data.explode('all_skills').groupby('all_skills'['dates'].value_counts().unstack('dates', fill_value=0)

output=data_ready.groupby(['all_skills']).sum()`






 all_skills 2020-11-01     2020-11-02
    'A'        1                  1  
    'B'        2                  0
    'S'        0                  2
    'H'        0                  2
    'R'        1                  0
```

Basically I am counting the frequency of elements of the list of `all_skills` if they have the same day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html?highlight=explode) the `all_skills` array and then group by and [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) and apply [`count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.groupby.GroupBy.count.html?highlight=count#pyspark.pandas.groupby.GroupBy.count) aggregation. Finally, apply [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html?highlight=coalesce#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) to poly-fill null values to `0`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(['A', 'B'], "2020-11-01",),
 (['B', 'I', 'R'], "2020-11-01",),
 (['S', 'H'], "2020-11-02",),
 (['A', 'H', 'S'], "2020-11-02",), ]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("all_skills", "dates",))

pivoted_df = (df.withColumn("all_skills", F.explode("all_skills"))
   .groupBy("all_skills")
   .pivot("dates")
   .agg(F.count("all_skills"))
)
final_df = pivoted_df.select([F.col("all_skills") if col_name == "all_skills" else F.coalesce(F.col(col_name), F.lit(0)).alias(col_name)  for col_name in pivoted_df.columns])

final_df.show()

"""
+----------+----------+----------+
|all_skills|2020-11-01|2020-11-02|
+----------+----------+----------+
|         B|         2|         0|
|         A|         1|         1|
|         S|         0|         2|
|         R|         1|         0|
|         I|         1|         0|
|         H|         0|         2|
+----------+----------+----------+
"""
```

Comment: Do you know how I can transpose the final result?

Comment: please reply if you can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503759/7989581 has the answer @user15649753

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for.

```
df1
.withColumn('skill', F.explode('all_skills')).drop('all_skills')
.groupBy("dates", "skill")
.agg(F.count("*")
.alias("count"))
.groupBy("skill")
.pivot("dates")
.agg(F.sum("count"))
.na.fill(0).show()
```