# How I can transpose a data frame in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I couldn't find any function in pyspark for transposing a dataframe.

```
Cal   Cal2   Cal3
'A'    12     11
'U'    10     9
'O'     5     5
'ER'    6     5


  
Cal    'A'   'U'   'O'   'ER'  
Cal2    12    10    5     6    
Cal3    11     9    5     5
```

in `pandas` is very easy:   `df.T`   but I am not sure how it is in `pyspark`!

Answer (score 7):

Generation of the sample dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('A' ,12 ,11),('U' ,10 ,9 ),('O' , 5 ,5 ),('ER', 6 ,5 )], ['Cal','Cal2','Cal3'])
```

**Option 1: [pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.T](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.T.html)**

For large dataframes [compute.max_rows](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//user_guide/pandas_on_spark/options.html) might be required

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps

ps.get_option("compute.max_rows") # 1000
ps.set_option("compute.max_rows", 2000)
```

---

```
(df
 .to_pandas_on_spark()
 .set_index('Cal')
 .T
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={"index":"Cal"})
 .to_spark()
 .show())

+----+---+---+---+---+
| Cal|  A|  U|  O| ER|
+----+---+---+---+---+
|Cal2| 12| 10|  5|  6|
|Cal3| 11|  9|  5|  5|
+----+---+---+---+---+
```

**Option 2: pyspark, the hard way**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

header_col = 'Cal'
cols_minus_header = df.columns
cols_minus_header.remove(header_col)

df1 = (df
       .groupBy()
       .pivot('Cal')
       .agg(F.first(F.array(cols_minus_header)))
       .withColumn(header_col, F.array(*map(F.lit, cols_minus_header)))
      )
```

---

```
df1.show(truncate = False)

+--------+------+------+-------+------------+
|       A|    ER|     O|      U|         Cal|
+--------+------+------+-------+------------+
|[12, 11]|[6, 5]|[5, 5]|[10, 9]|[Cal2, Cal3]|
+--------+------+------+-------+------------+
```

---

```
df2 = df1.select(F.arrays_zip(*df1.columns).alias('az')).selectExpr('inline(az)')
```

---

```
df2.show(truncate = False)

+---+---+---+---+----+
|A  |ER |O  |U  |Cal |
+---+---+---+---+----+
|12 |6  |5  |10 |Cal2|
|11 |5  |5  |9  |Cal3|
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: clever way to use structs and then an inline..+1

Comment: which one is more efficient?

Comment: I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.pandas'

Comment: the second method didn't work as well

Comment: It's a tested code.  First option might not be supported by your version.  2nd should work fine.  Recheck your code and share the error if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can `unpivot` the dataframe and then `pivot` it based on a different column.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [('A', 12, 11,),
 ('U', 10, 9,),
 ('O', 5, 5,),
 ('ER', 6, 5,), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Cal", "Cal2", "Cal3",))

key_column = "Cal"
unpivot_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x != key_column]
unpivot_col_expr = " ,".join([f"'{c}', {c}" for c in unpivot_cols])

unpivot_expr = f"stack({len(unpivot_cols)}, {unpivot_col_expr}) as (key,value)"
unpivoted_df = df.select("Cal", F.expr(unpivotExpr))

unpivoted_df.groupBy("key").pivot(key_column).agg(F.first("value")).withColumnRenamed("key", key_column).show()

"""
+----+---+---+---+---+
| Cal|  A| ER|  O|  U|
+----+---+---+---+---+
|Cal3| 11|  5|  5|  9|
|Cal2| 12|  6|  5| 10|
+----+---+---+---+---+
"""
```

Answer (score -1):

With Spark 3.2.1 supports pyspark supports pandas API as well.

If your dataframe is small you can make use of the same.

> This method is based on an expensive operation due to the nature of big data. Internally it needs to generate each row for each value, and then group twice - it is a huge operation. To prevent misusage, this method has the ‘compute.max_rows’ default limit of input length, and raises a ValueError.

See the below link for more details - 
[pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.transpose)

In addition to the above, you can also use Koalas (available in databricks) and is similar to Pandas except makes more sense for distributed processing and available in Pyspark (from 3.0.0 onwards). Something as below -

```
kdf = df.to_koalas()
Transpose_kdf = kdf.transpose()
TransposeDF = Transpose_kdf.to_spark()
```

Koalas documentation - [Databricks Koalas](https://docs.databricks.com/languages/koalas.html)

One thing to note is, you need to define partitions so as to use Koalas efficiently, else there could be serious performance issues.

There is another option that pyspark natively provides is `pivot` and `stack` option. See the below documentation for details - 
[Stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack) 
[Pivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html) 
I'll leave these two for you to explore in detail.

Comment: You might want to read the links that you shared

Comment: What exactly is wrong in these links? Question is related to transposing a dataframe. I suggested `pyspark pandas` & `databricks koalas` API.

Comment: Other than thee cod that you supplied for Koalas, all the rest is just name dropping, and if you have actually read the links you would have seen that "Koalas is deprecated on clusters that run Databricks Runtime 10.0 and above", which is due to the merging of the Koalas project to pyspark as part of project Zen. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34849

Comment: I'm currently using Databricks Runtime 9.1 LTS. Haven't migrated to ver.10. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: Ran some tests, and in addition to "FutureWarning: DataFrame.to_koalas is deprecated. Use DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark instead." there is also an error "ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'int' object". Same error for pyspark pandas

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz my guess it because columns expect string values and transposing on a range index tries to set `int`s as columns which is not allowed (but should have been addressed in docs -citation needed) . However , setting the `Cal` column as index worked and that is what will might be required: `df.to_pandas_on_spark().set_index("Cal").transpose().reset_index().to_spark().show()`

Comment: @anky - Yep. that fixed it