# Transposing or pivoting a dataframe in databricks pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

Appreciate hints on how to go about pivoting/transposing a dataframe in such a way that I will have the transposed Cx name column as a concatenation of the Cx names separated by a comma.
[image]

I have found the advice provided here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474821/how-i-can-transpose-a-data-frame-in-pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com) , very useful, however just need some pointers now on next step to have the final results look like this:
[image]

Code that I used, credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6336479/david-%d7%93%d7%95%d7%93%d7%95-markovitz is shown below:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, asc
ps.get_option("compute.max_rows") # 1000
ps.set_option("compute.max_rows", 2000)
df = spark.createDataFrame([('12345','John Doe',1),('12345','Jane Doe',2)],['Acct' , 'CxName' ,'Position' ])
df = df.sort(asc('position'))
df.display()
```

```
(df
#  .to_pandas_on_spark()
 .pandas_api()
 .set_index('Position')
 .T
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={"index":"Position"})
 .to_spark()
 .show())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Code

```
df1 = df.groupBy('Acct').agg(F.expr("collect_list(struct(Position, CxName)) AS CxName"))
df1 = df1.withColumn('CxName', F.expr("transform(array_sort(CxName), x -> x['CxName'])"))
df1 = df1.withColumn('CxName', F.expr("array_join(CxName, ',')"))
```

#### How this works

Group the dataframe by `Acct` and collect the pairs of `Position`, `CxName`

```
+-----+------------------------------+
|Acct |CxName                        |
+-----+------------------------------+
|12345|[{1, John Doe}, {2, Jane Doe}]|
+-----+------------------------------+
```

Sort the pairs inside array by their position and transform the sorted pairs to extract the value of `CxName`

```
+-----+--------------------+
|Acct |CxName              |
+-----+--------------------+
|12345|[John Doe, Jane Doe]|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Join the values in the array around the delimiter `','`

```
+-----+-----------------+
|Acct |CxName           |
+-----+-----------------+
|12345|John Doe,Jane Doe|
+-----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Great! I now have a much better understanding of how to approach with your code, I am guessing that this approach would be much kinder on computing resources as well ... much appreciated, https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma

Comment: @DanA happy coding ~